# How can I run chromecast sample without whitelisting

Tags: chromecast

When I try to write my custom app, I am asked to white list the device. But how can I run the sample apps without whitelisting my chromecast device.

Sample apps here, https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the app on your [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/applications). Once it is added, click on your application and publish the app. As stated:

> When published, your application can be launched on any device. When
>   unpublished, your application can only be launched on your authorized
>   devices.

Comment: Yes, how can I launch when its unpublished?

Comment: Hi Phil,
I've submitted my iOS app integrated with chromecast.
Its working fine in my chromecast device, which I've registered in the google developer console, but not with the other devices(customers were not able to use the app to cast to their tv with their chromecast device).
In the developer console, we gave a url for the chromecast.html(receiver page) which is actually a http link, Is it mandatory to use HTTPS(secured) link to get it work for all chromecast device ?
Would that be the reason why my customers were not able to cast the video to their chromecast device ?

Comment: @PradeepRajkumar this is an entirely new question. Click [*Ask a new Question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and paste this text on the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own receiver, you have no choice but to whitelist your device for your app (unless you decide to publish your app which is not a good idea). You can use the app id that is provided in that project and that refers to a published on but that is not your receiver anymore.

Comment: Where can I find the instructions for running an unpublished app, using the default receiver, on a non-whitelisted device?

Comment: Google should improve documentation for Chromecast

Comment: CommonsWare: for Default receiver, you can use the app id's that various platforms expose, see https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default

Comment: dcanh121: if you have suggestions that are specific or concrete, please open an Enhancement issue on our tracker or post on our community, otherwise a generic sentence like "improve your documentation" is not considered valuable.

Comment: "you can use the app id's that various platforms expose" -- OK, and what about `RemotePlaybackClient` apps that do not specify a receiver, nor use/need the Cast SDK?

Comment: @dcanh121: BTW, [here is the Google Cast issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list).

Comment: @AliNaddaf When I try to run the app, I get this error http://stackoverflow.com/q/22515205/563306 Perhaps you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: @dcanh121: I already left a comment there in that post, did you follow that?

Comment: Never mind, `RemotePlaybackClient` works fine with non-whitelisted devices. My apologies.