# cannot run chromecast app

Tags: android, chromecast

I am trying to the exact sample app (https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android) with my own package name, put the receiver code on my server.

I registered the app, and my device on the chromecast developer console.

When I try to launch the app, I get this error,

```
03-19 11:33:14.268: D/DeviceFilter(1060): Sending text message to chromecast: (ns=urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.tp.connection, dest=receiver-0) {"origin":{},"package":"gms_cast_mrp","type":"CONNECT"}
03-19 11:33:14.268: D/DeviceFilter(1060): Sending text message to chromecast: (ns=urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.receiver, dest=receiver-0) {"type":"GET_APP_AVAILABILITY","requestId":1,"appId":["69FFFAE0"]}
03-19 11:33:14.268: D/DeviceFilter(1060): onMessageReceived: gms_cast_mrp-21
03-19 11:33:14.268: D/DeviceFilter(1060): Received a protobuf: axm@426978b8
03-19 11:33:14.268: D/DeviceFilter(1060): Sending text message to chromecast: (ns=urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.tp.connection, dest=receiver-0) {"type":"CLOSE"}
03-19 11:33:14.268: D/DeviceFilter(1060): rejected device: "chromecast" (70e0019191420559fedfca4f6129b935)
03-19 11:33:14.278: D/CastSocket(1060): doTeardown with reason=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your device was not correctly whitelisted. Did you check the box to send its serial number when you were setting up your chromecast? See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/2765813) in case it helps ...

Comment: Yes I did send the serial number. I'm periodically checking chromecast if it works.

Comment: As long as you cannot access port 9222 for debugging, your device has not been whitelisted. if it has been a while, you might want to double check on your serial number, etc.

Comment: I finally got my chromecast whitelisted. I can run published apps, but cannot run unpublished apps. It still says rejected device.

Comment: How did you verify that your device is whitelisted?

Comment: I just assumed since earlier I couldn't run my own published app, but now I can

Comment: did you see my comments a few lines above: As long as you cannot access port 9222 for debugging, your device has not been whitelisted. Please follow steps carefully and do not skip over any of them and then come back with more data to share.